# Error opening terminal: vt102

Tags: linux

When i try to open a dialog binary on my linux machine i am getting the following error: `Error opening terminal: vt102`

I cross compiled dialog and ncurses both for ARM and compilation went fine but binary opening is giving me an error. Command which is giving the error is:

```
$DIALOG --clear --backtitle "Accept EULA to proceed" --title "END USER LICENSE AGREEMENT" --no-mouse --no-lines --extra-button --ok-label 'Accept' --extra-label 'Decline' "$@" --textbox /vss/scripts/End-User-Product-License-Agmt.txt 0 0
```

Comment: What's your `$TERM`?

Comment: /etc # echo $TERM
xterm

Answer (score 2):

The message says that ncurses cannot find the terminal description for **`vt102`**.  That could happen because

- the default compiled-in pathname for the terminal database does not match the location where you installed the terminal database, or
- you did not install the terminal database.

Both of those are (probably) easy to do in cross-compiling.  When you run the configure script, it prints the important pathnames at the end, because those can all be customized.  For example:

```
** Configuration summary for NCURSES 6.0 20170909:

       extended funcs: yes
       xterm terminfo: xterm-new

        bin directory: /usr/bin
        lib directory: /usr/lib
    include directory: /usr/include/ncursesw6
        man directory: /usr/share/man
   terminfo directory: /usr/local/ncurses/share/terminfo
 pkg-config directory: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
```

If you do not override the pathname for the terminal database at runtime (with [`TERMINFO`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-TERMINFO) and/or [`TERMINFO_DIRS`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-TERMINFO_DIRS)), it uses the compiled-in pathnames.

To install the terminal database, you could use [`tic`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tic.1m.html), e.g.,

```
tic -x terminfo.src
```

or copy the directory tree with the terminal database from another machine.

Further reading:

- [The terminfo database is big—do I need all of that?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#big_terminfo)
- [Which terminfo database do I need?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#which_terminfo)

Comment: there is a terminfo.src file in ncurses folder. Do i need to change that?

Comment: That is a source-file.  You would compile that (into binary form) using `tic`.  By the way, `tic` (by default) will use the same pathname as ncurses would use to find the information...

Comment: compiled terminfo.src, then compiled ncurses, used it in compilation of dialog. still i am getting same error

Comment: If you install terminfo.src using one version of `tic`, and compile ncurses with another, the paths may differ.  `infocmp vt102` would show if ncurses can find that entry.